# Setting a div to show an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to set an Array to be the innerHTML of a div created by the script so show the array on ever step of the sort Function. I am getting

> Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null.

arr is the name of the array.

Here is the code I am using:

```
function bubbleSort(arr){
    var swapped,
        container = document.getElementById("container"),
        o = 0;
    console.log("entered bubbleSort");
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (var i=0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
            console.log(arr);
            o + 1;
            container.innerHTML += '<div id = "div"+ o></div>';
            document.getElementById("div" + o).innerHTML = arr[i];
            if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
                var temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swapped)
}
```

Comment: `'<div id = "div"+ o></div>'` should be `'<div id = "div' + o + '"></div>'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the new elements this way:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.id = "div"+o;
container.appendChild(newDiv);
document.getElementById("div" + o).innerHTML = arr[i];
```

Edit:
You actually had just a typo. See RobG comment. This method is just more efficient, and won't remove previously bound events.

A working JSFiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/5pdax3wt/)

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code. The following line:

```
o + 1;
```

does nothing. I think you mean to increment `o`, so use:

```
++o;
```

Also, there is a typo in the following line:

```
container.innerHTML += '<div id = "div"+ o></div>';
                                      ^^^^^
```

What you should have used is:

```
container.innerHTML += '<div id="div' + o + '"></div>';
                                     ^^^^^^^
```

You might find using DOM methods more convenient, but here is your original function with the typo fixed:

```js
function bubbleSort(arr) {
  var swapped,
    container = document.getElementById("container"),
    o = 0;
  console.log("entered bubbleSort");
  do {
    swapped = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
      console.log(arr);
      ++o;
      container.innerHTML += '<div id="div' + o + '"></div>';

      document.getElementById("div" + o).innerHTML = arr[i];

      if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
        var temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        arr[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
  } while (swapped)
}

bubbleSort([2,1,3]);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```